# Login via Facebook fails with no error in Android

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform

So I've been using login via Facebook in my app and it was working fine on the emulator using the debug keyhash. I recently published my app for beta testing on PlayStore and replaced the keyhash of the app on Facebook with the new one signed with the new keystore. After trying several methods to obtain the correct keyhash (none worked) I used the one that appeared as an error when I ran the app.

After that, whenever I try to login via Facebook, it doesn't show any wrong keyhash errors, it shows nothing at all! It just calls the failure callback through Parse. Logcat doesn't show anything also.

Is there something I can do?

**EDIT:** I managed to get it working on the emulator using the build download through PlayStore (not debug) but it still doesn't work on other devices!

Comment: Have you done created facebook app live ?

Comment: You mean publish it through Facebook? No, I didn't. Could this be the issue?

Comment: I've been through Facebook docs again and there's no mention about requiring your app to go live first. It should work just by creating a new app..